# How to send error message to a particular mail using mailman server in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

Hi I need to send an exception message to a particular mail in mailman server using action Mailer. Please if anybody knows the answer please let me know. Any help would be grateful

Comment: I just want to make sure if I understood the problem correctly. when a exception is thrown on your app you want to get a email

Comment: if that is the case take a look at https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification